# How do I reduce the Nested tags in an XML payload to fit into an existing object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jaxb

I have a class that contains various nested objects that needs to be parsed to xml using JAX-B , this is the sample class object being passed as XML payload :

```
<creditTransactionMessage>
    <finToFinCreditTransaction>
        <transactionHeader>
            <totalInterBankSettlementAmount>
                <settlementAmount>2780.00</settlementAmount>
                <ccy>NGN</ccy>
            </totalInterBankSettlementAmount>
        </transactionHeader>
        <creditTransaction>
            <creditTransaction>
                <beneficiaryBank>
                    <beneficiaryBankIdentificiation>
```

What I want is to reduce the number of nested objects in the payload to just something like this :

```
<settlementAmount>2780.00</settlementAmount>
 <ccy>NGN</ccy>
```

Without having to declared the top nested object levels . Such that the new payload goes into the existing object class with sample payload as posted above .